# What components can be included in Google Sheets Add-on?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-addon

I am building a Google Apps Script application for Google Sheets that I would like to deploy as an add-on in the [Google GSuite Marketplace](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace). My application has three components:

1. An embedded custom menu and set of dialog boxes within Google Sheets that allow one set of app users ("User Group 1") to manipulate spreadsheet data
2. A web app that provides another set of users ("User Group 2") with mobile device access to different set of functionality that involves spreadsheet data
3. Template sheets (ideally, hidden from the user) that the app can use to generate additional sheets programmatically as needed.

I would like to deploy all components as part of a single add-on. I'd like components 1 and 2 to be bound to the same spreadsheet. In fact, I'd like someone in "User Group 1" to be able to click a button to get the URL for the web app. This would require the ability to peform functions on the "Publish" menu through Apps Script code.

My reading of [the documentation on add-ons](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/) makes no mention of the ability to deploy an add on that includes (a) a UI embedded within Google Sheets, (b) an associated web app that operates on the same user spreadsheet, and (c) template (hidden) sheets. Does anyone have any experience with this, or suggestions on how to proceed?

At present, the only solution I see is to deploy two separate apps (components 1 and 2), but then the web app would not be bound to a specific spreadsheet and hence would need to use a different API. As for accessing template sheets, I *think* it's possible to access an external sheet through a URL, but I do not think it's possible for an add-on to include template sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Number 1**

[Add-on User interface](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/#user_interfaces)

> Add-ons can create **menu items** and **open dialogs** or **sidebars**. For custom interfaces, the HTML service offers client-side HTML, CSS, and JS with a few limitations: notably, our security sandbox doesn't work with many JS libraries.

[Custom sidebars](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_sidebars)

> A sidebar can display an HTML service user interface inside a **Google Docs, Forms, or Sheets editor**.

---

**Number 2**

I am not completely sure that I understand your deployment question - [however](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)

> Both **standalone scripts** and **scripts bound** to G Suite applications **can be turned into web apps**, so long as they meet the requirements below.

I was able to deploy both an add-on and a web app from a single [Standalone](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone) script

---

**Number 3**

Use the [copyTo(Spreadsheet)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copyTo(Spreadsheet)) to copy a sheet from a different spreadsheet to the one you are working on and change the name with [setName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setName(String)).

Or you can make a template sheet in the same spreadsheet and use [hideSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hideSheet())

Comment: Thanks, @random-parts! With respect to Question Number 3, can I actually include a sheet as part of an add on? I know how to copy a sheet, but the question is how to get the sheet in the first place. Must it be _programmatically_ generated from the add on, or can I include the sheet (as a template sheet) as part of the add on?

Comment: Im not sure Im understanding what you are asking; there is [insertSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertSheet(String,Integer,Object)) to insert new sheets from another one. You can get the sheet from other spreadsheets or the same spreadsheet by its file ID

Comment: I'm interesting in deploying my app as an add-on. I would like the template sheet to be deployed as part of the add-on, so that I can make copies of it in the spreadsheet on which the add-on is operating. Are you saying I will need to perform a copy from another (external) spreadsheet to achieve this behavior?

Comment: No. Have you read the docs or [insertSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertSheet(String,Integer,Object)) ? [insertSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertSheet(String,Integer,Object)) will use a sheet already in the spreadsheet as a template for new sheets, [copyTo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copyTo(Spreadsheet)) will copy a sheet between spreadsheets then you can use that as the new sheet or as a template sheet to insert more new sheets etc